# Jquery AJAX - using http or https?

Tags: jquery, ajax

By default does an ajax request use HTTP or HTTPS ?

I'm using the following code to submit a form to a local page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    url: "local.php",   
    success: function(data) {
        console.log (data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log (data)
    }
});
```

How do I determine if the submission is done using http or https ?

Is there a way to set which protocol should be used ?

Thanks

Comment: By default it will use whatever the page is loaded over.

Comment: There is no default behavior for AJAX request. It all depends on the url parameter(protocol and address are generally specified)  if it uses http or https.
In your case, since you are calling a local page, ajax will use whatever your website is loaded over.

Comment: Thanks, 've been watching the output in the console and it does appear to show http or https correctly depending how I access the system. I'm checking this as we are seeing an error in the console `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` is that due to the protocol and ajax request ?